# How do I directly read the timezone files included in the JRE distribution?

Tags: java, timezone

Timezone information for Java are kept in a folder called "zi". For eg.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk6\jre\lib\zi

files in this folder are in binary format. But it is very important for me to see exactly what they say.

Can anyone share a way,  to read these files, or are they Sun proprietary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like almost all current operating systems and other software environments. Java uses the zoneinfo format for timezone information. You can start with the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo) page, or just Google for zoneinfo.

There are a number of tools to process zoneinfo files, you should be able to extract the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You will find here a good example of [zoneinfo updating process](http://seer.entsupport.symantec.com/docs/301500.htm), with the [tzupdater](http://java.sun.com/javase/tzupdater_README.html) tool.

Note that different versions of the jdk include [different versions](http://java.sun.com/javase/timezones/tzdata_versions.html) of the Olson timezone data, involving different versions of the [tzupdater tool](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp#timezone).

Java have its timezone in [its own format](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t149712-java-time-zones.html).